# getParcelable crashes on release mode but works fine when install through android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, parcelable

```
public class Details implements Parcelable {

@Ignore
protected Details(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readLong();
    timestamp = in.readString();
    type = in.readInt();
}


@Ignore
public static final Creator<Details> CREATOR = new Creator<Details>() {
    @Override
    public Details createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Details(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Details[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Details[size];
    }
};

}
```

Using bundle to move data to fragment.

```
DetailsManagementIncomeFragment fragment = new DetailsManagementIncomeFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("details", details);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

in createView, it blacks out in release mode only, actually it hangs.

```
Details details = getArguments().getParcelable("details");
```

Not able to debug it in android studio as it works fine there.

Comment: Please copy the crash (exception and stack trace logs) from logcat into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Crash in release and not is debug points to code obfuscation done by ProGaurd. Refer https://medium.com/programming-lite/secure-your-codes-by-enabling-proguard-in-android-app-bbbc003144b5 for more details. I recommend keeping your model class in Keep.xml so that it won't get obfuscated.